# doGet code how to use ? GOOGLE APP SCRIPT

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I try below code, while the "e.parameter"always shown "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parameter')",can anyone help on that ?Appreciate any suggestion.

body

```
function doGet(e) {
  var SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var params = e.parameter;              // 讀取網址參數
  var name = params.name || 'Mainsheet'; // 如果有 name 就使用，否則 name 等於「工作表1」
  var SheetName = SpreadSheet.getSheetByName(name) ;  // 讀取工作表名稱為 name 的資料
  var start_row = params.start_row || 1; // 如果有 start_row 就使用，否則 start_row 等於 1
  var start_col = params.start_col || 1; // 如果有 start_row 就使用，否則 start_col 等於 1
  var row = params.row || SheetName.getLastRow() - start_row + 1;   // 如果有 row 就使用，否則 row 等於 SheetName.getLastRow()
  var col = params.col|| SheetName.getLastColumn() - start_col + 1; // 如果有 col 就使用，否則 col 等於 SheetName.getLastColumn()
  var data = SheetName.getSheetValues(start_row,start_col,row,col);  // 使用變數
  Logger.log(data)
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON); 
}
```

---

[image: snapshot]

---

Comment: How are you executing the doGet(e)?  The doGet() is meant to be an end point to a call from another script or a webapp and you must supply the event object.  If you call it from the command line it will always fail with a message like that.